# haproxy stick-table output fields

Tags: haproxy

I currently define a stick table as:

```
  stick-table type string len 56 size 2k expire 10s store gpc0_rate(60s)
```

When I run,

```
echo "show table elb_in"  | socat unix-connect:/var/run/haproxy.sock stdio
```

I see:

```
0x7f74122fdfec: key=Go-http-client/1.1 use=355 exp=9865 gpc0_rate(60000)=6636
```

Can someone please shed some light on what does the `use` mean?

I know `exp` stands for expiry.

Answer (score 1):

The table fields are not very well documented in the [API](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/2-2r1/api/runtime-api/show-table/) or the HAProxy documentation. But there are references to it being a reference counter for concurrent sessions that are tracking the key.

For example: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#7.3.1-table_trackers

> If the key is not found in the table, integer value zero
> is returned. Otherwise the converter returns the current amount of concurrent
> connections tracking the same key as the input sample in the designated
> table. It differs from table_conn_cur in that it does not rely on any stored
> information but on the table's reference count (the "use" value which is
> returned by "show table" on the CLI).

In your example that would mean for the key `Go-http-client/1.1` there are `355` concurrent sessions tracking that key via a [`track-scX` statement](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20track-sc0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer finally! :)